# That always be or that's always be

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Which one is correct:

1. My mom always be the first.
2. My mom is always be the first.

I'm always confused about using is/am/are and be. Can they be used in a sentence just like the sentence in number 2? Or is it correct to say 1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In standard English neither is grammatical. *Be* is not a finite verb in the third person, nor is it a form that can follow *is*.

The simplest variant that is grammatical is

> My mom is always the first.

I'm guessing that your use of *be* is intended to convey her determination to be the first. The most idiomatic way of saying that is

> My mom always has to be the first.

There is no form of *be* that clearly expresses habitual behaviour.

Comment: It seems to me that *My mom **will** [always] be drunk and embarrass the family* (with heavy stress on the highlighted auxiliary) can express "habitual" behaviour even without ***always***.

Comment: Not anumbiguously, @FumbleFingers: it could also be used referring to a specific event.

Comment: Agreed, it's not "anumbiguous" (not "pacifically" so, anyway! :) I didn't fully take on board the implications of ***clearly** expresses habitual behaviour* - which in context clearly means ***unambiguously*** (and all ad-hoc synonyms thereof! :)